# Can connect two bluetooth devices to the Raspberry Pi B +?

Tags: bluetooth, gps

I have a question: Can connect two bluetooth devices (GPS and OBD) operates under a [bluetooth adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KAE3GPW) to the Raspberry Pi B+?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

using the power of `google://"connect 2 bluetooth devices"` you may easily find that [Bluetooth can connect up to eight devices simultaneously.](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/bluetooth2.htm)

Comment: But will this work *on the Raspberry Pi*? Sure, you can connect up to 8 Bluetooth devices, but is this possible on the Raspberry Pi? We have to remember drivers and stuffs.